# Computing the maximum likelihood estimator

Tags: statistical-inference, maximum-likelihood

> **Problem**: Consider a random sample of size $n$ that follows a  density probability function given by:
>
> > $$f(x,\theta)=\frac{1}{\theta} x^{-\frac{\theta+1}{\theta}}\mathbb{1}_{(1,+\infty)},\:\:\theta>0$$
>
> where $\theta$ is unknown.
>
> **1)** Determine the maximum likelihood estimator of $\theta$? Is the found estimator consistent?
>
> **2)**Provide an sufficient statistic for this model.

**1)**

$L=\prod_\limits{i=1}^{n}f(x,\theta)=\frac{1}{{\theta}^n} x^{-\frac{{(\theta+1)}^n}{{\theta}^n}}\mathbb{1}_{(1,+\infty)}$

In order to find $\theta$ I have to compute:

$\frac{dL}{d\theta}=0\implies\frac {d{\frac{1}{{\theta}^n} x^{-\frac{{(\theta+1)}^n}{{\theta}^n}}\mathbb{1}_{(1,+\infty)}}{}}{d\theta}=0$

However this derivative is very difficult to calculate.

For the second question I was thinking about the maximum likelihood estimator as a possible sufficient estimator.

**Question**:

Is there another way to find the maximum likelihood ratio besides the derivative?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Likelihood is $L(\theta)=\prod_{i=1}^n f(x_i,\theta)$. You can take the log-likelihood and then differentiate if that's easier. And for identifying sufficient statistic, use Factorization theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition of likelihood is incorrect.  Yours assumes each data point has the same value.  Instead, each can (and does) have a *different* value.  Replace $x$ by $x_i$ and then perform your derivative with respect to $\theta$.

$$L = \frac{1}{\theta^n} \left[ x_1^{(1-\theta)/\theta} x_2^{(1-\theta)/\theta} \cdots x_n^{(1-\theta)/\theta} \right]$$

It is simplest, though, to work with the *log*likelihood...

$$l \equiv \ln L = - n \ln \theta + \frac{1-\theta}{\theta} \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \ln x_i$$

Now compute $$\frac{d l}{d \theta} = \frac{-n}{\theta} + \frac{1}{\theta (\theta - 1)} \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \ln x_i$$

and set it to zero to find:

$$\hat{\theta} = \left( \frac{1}{n} \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \ln x_i \right) + 1$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I computed everything and I got $\theta=\frac{1}{n}\sum_\limits{i=1}^{n}\log(x_i)$

Comment: @PedroGomes:  Check your calculations...

Comment: @PedroGomes Right answer should be $\hat\theta=-\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n \ln (x_i)$.